# Geometric Series Transformation - Introduction to Algorithms 15.1-1

Tags: summation, induction, geometric-series

For problem 15.1-1 in the Introduction to Algorithms book, the question asks, "Show that equation (15.4) follows from equation (15.3) and the initial condition T(0) = 1

In one of the many solutions on the internet, it shows the following transformation  is a geometric series such that:

$$T(n) = 1 +  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T(j) = 1 +  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^j $$

Could someone explain how you know that T(j) is $2^{j}$ in this partial solution I found?

Comment: Please post the problem.

Comment: Changed the word "problem" to "solution".  Example solution can be found http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/Ch15.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It is true for $n=1$ since $$T(1)=1+ \sum_{i=0}^{0} T(i)=1+1=2=2^1$$
Now suppose it is true for $n$, that is
$$T(n) =  1 +  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 2^j=1+\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}=2^n$$
and let's prove it for $n+1$
$$T(n+1)=1+\sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^j=2^n+2^n=2\cdot 2^n=2^{n+1}$$
so the formula is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How do you know in the first step that T(0) is 1 where you have 1 + 1 = 2 ...What would it look like if you had n = 3 for example?  This is the part I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Several versions of the same hint.

- Look at $1, 1+2, 1+2+4, 1+2+4+8, \ldots$. You should see the pattern.
- Look up or remember the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.
- Think about the largest number you can represent in binary with $n$ bits.
- Try to write down the straightforward induction argument.

Comment: How do you know that T(j) is $2^j$  I don't see anywhere where T(j) is defined.

Comment: @user1522163 $T(j)$ is defined by the formula in your question. There's now a correct answer here.

Comment: I have not seen an answer to my question.  I specifically ask how T(j) becomes $2^j$ in the sample solution provided.

Comment: @Raffaele s solution starts with knowing $T(1)=1 + T(0) = 2^1$ (since $T(0)=1$ is given), then proves by induction that whenever you happen to know that $T(n) = 2^n$ you can use that and the given formula to show that $T(n+1) = 2^{n+1}$. If you don't follow that argument you have to work more to understand mathematical induction.